# Change the Center color of doughnut chart in Chart.Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chart.js

Is there a way to change the color of the middle circle in Chart.Js? I don't seem to find it on their documentation?

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use chart.js 3.8

```
const colorcenter = {
  id: 'colorcenter',
  beforeDraw(chart, args, options) {
    const {ctx, chartArea: {top, right, bottom, left, width, height}} = chart;
    const radius = chart._metasets[0].controller.innerRadius;
    const x = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0].x;
    const y = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0].y
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = options.backgroundColor;
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The background is transparent. I think you can't really color the midle circle..
The main  option is to put a background color on canvas or chart but all the white spaces will be colored.

Comment: Yeah, the white spaces are also colored. Looking for workaround. Didnt find any sample code yet.

Comment: There is a workaround : you can draw a circle on the canvas in the background of chart.

It may help you : http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-circles/

Answer (score 0):

its transparent , takes background colour